# Issue Deploying Spring Boot Project to Azure Web App via VS Code

Tags: spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I'm currently attempting to deploy a Spring Boot project to an Azure Web App Resource using Visual Studio Code (VS Code). To achieve this, I've been following the instructions outlined in the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-webapp).  As part of the process, I cloned a sample Spring Boot project from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot.git)  mentioned in the documentation.

Despite meticulously following each step, I encountered an obstacle. My intention was to deploy the project's .jar file to the web app. However, I encountered an error message in VS Code that reads: "Path specified is not a war file."

The confusing part is that the documentation I referred to explicitly states that a .jar file can be deployed to the web app. Yet, I'm facing this error. Could someone please guide me through this issue and help me understand why this error is occurring for me when the documentation suggests otherwise?

I've attached relevant screenshots for reference:

1. **Deploying Spring Project Screenshot:**

[image]

2. **Error Message Screenshot:**

[image]

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your requirement in my environment by cloning the same [GitHub repository](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot) and I could deploy the Jar file.

Follow the below steps:

- **Delete the below highlighted jar files:**

[image]

Go to Terminal, Run `mvn clean install`:

- It will clean the project and generate the Jar files again.

[image]
[image]

**Check if the project working locally:**

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

- Create a new App Service with **JAVA 17** as Runtime stack in Azure Portal.
- **Try to deploy the Jar file to the newly created Web App:**

[image]
[image]

**Deployment Status:**

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

---

**Updated Answer:**

**Deploy using Maven commands:**

Go to terminal, run the below given command in the folder path where your `pom.xml` exists:

> mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:2.5.0:config

Select the options such as web app, OS, Java version according to your requirement.

[image]

Run the same command again and choose options accordingly:

> mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:2.5.0:config

[image]

Run `mvn package azure-webapps:deploy` to deploy the application to Azure app service:

[image]

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: I have tried same thing still getting same Error: "Path specified is not a war file." , Is it VS code or maven versions etc.. problem?

Comment: Did you delete snapshot.jar files as I mentioned in the answer?

Comment: @Balu, Check the updated answer. Follow the steps given and try to deploy using **Maven commands**.

Comment: Yes deleted and rebuild with mvn clean install command, then started deployment still getting same error.

Comment: Delete the current project which you have now, clone it again from [GitHub repo](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot) and try to deploy again.

Comment: Hi Pravalika, I've cloned project agaian in another directory, then tried to deploy by follwoing your steps clearly still getting same ERROR: Path specified is not a war file.FYI I've Used Two laptops got same error. my VS Code version is 1.81.1 and Maven version is 3.9.3....  :(

Comment: This could be issue with Maven version, try to uninstall and install Maven again

Comment: No pravalika, I've updated my maven version to latest one still coming same Error :(

Comment: What is the Runtime stack you are selecting while creating Azure App Service? Try with Tomcat 8 version

Comment: Hi pravalika it is working now, Thanks!